# Independence from random vector eith joint density function

Tags: integration, independence

If (X,Y) is a random vector with the following joint density function

f(x,y) =\begin{cases} 
      \pi^{-1} \; \; x^2 + y^2\leq 1 \\
      0 \; \text{elsewhere}
   \end{cases}

Are X and Y independent?

My approach:

I know that they are independent if $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$

So

1. integrate wrt to x from $-\infty$ to 1
2. integrate wrt to y from $-\infty$ to 1

Then multiply the two results and see if it equals f(x,y).

Is that the right approach? I'm especially unsure about the bounds for the integrals.

Comment: Draw the support of $X,Y$. This way you can calculate the marginals more easily.

Comment: Do you mean to visualize it better or? Is -inf to 1 the right support for both integrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support of $X,Y$ is $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$. This is
[image]

Now, for $X$ we have:
\begin{align*}
-1 \leq x \leq 1, \quad -\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}
\end{align*}
$$
f_{X}(x) = \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \frac{1}{\pi} dy
$$
for $Y$ we have
\begin{align*}
-1 \leq y \leq 1, \quad -\sqrt{1-y^2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{1-y^2}
\end{align*}
$$
f_{Y}(y) = \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \frac{1}{\pi} dx
$$